# Javascript finding a nested object within a nested object with regex and object property

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm turning a string into an object, then looping over that object. For some reason, if the string is semi-correctly formatted and I don't do the first two steps (replacing the parentheses with curly brackets) it works fine.

However, the replacement puts single ' instead of " (although it still parses without error). The parse misses putting the second id underneath the employeeType, and mistakenly puts it under employee.

https://codepen.io/MrMooCats/pen/zwpQGa

```
var str = "(id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id),lastname),location)";

str = str.replace(/[(]/g, "{"); // Possible problem line?
str = str.replace(/[)]/g, "}"); // Possible problem line?
str = str.replace(/([A-z])\s*{/g, "$1\":{");
str = str.replace(/([A-z])\s*([},])/g, "$1\":null$2");
str = str.replace(/({)/g, "{\"");
str = str.replace(/(,)/g, ",\"");
var objectStr = JSON.parse(str); // Object created, but wrong


var objectOutput = function(obj, counter) {
    for(var i in obj) {
      console.log(Array(counter+1).join("-") + " " + i);
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
          if (obj[i] != null) {
            objectOutput(obj[i], counter+1);
          } else {
            counter = 0;
          }
        }
    }
};

objectOutput(objectStr, 0);
```

Actual output:

```
" id"

" created"

" employee"

"- id"

" firstname"

" employeeType"

"- id"

" lastname"

" location"
```

Expected Output

```
" id"

" created"

" employee"

"- id"

"- firstname"

"- lastname"

"- employeeType"

"-- id"

" location"
```

Comment: I guess my first question would be, how is your string supposed to be formatted? And why are you using a string to create an object?

Comment: `// Works fine if the ( are { instead and remove the first two lines` - that's unreadable, can you just show what works?

Comment: I added a codepen, it has all the code exactly as here and the output

Comment: That codepen isn't very useful.  How is your string actually going to be formatted? Do you have an example?  Why do you use a string? Where is it coming from? @Organiccat

Comment: *...the replacement puts single ' instead of "...* I don't know what that means. There are no single quotes in the replaced string. *...The parse misses putting the second id underneath the employeeType, and mistakenly puts it under employee...* Don't know what you mean there either. The second `id` *is* under `employee`.

Comment: I added actual and expected outputs, I think that should clear things up

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the parsing and is really about how you're outputting the result.

Comment: @Organiccat see my answer that produces what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get desired output you need to fix your `objectOutput` functrion:

```js
    // Works fine if the ( are { instead and remove the first two lines
    var str = "(id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id),lastname),location)";

    str = str.replace(/[(]/g, "{"); // Possible problem line?
    str = str.replace(/[)]/g, "}"); // Possible problem line?
    str = str.replace(/([A-z])\s*{/g, "$1\":{");
    str = str.replace(/([A-z])\s*([},])/g, "$1\":null$2");
    str = str.replace(/({)/g, "{\"");
    str = str.replace(/(,)/g, ",\"");
    var objectStr = JSON.parse(str); // Object created, but wrong


    var objectOutput = function(obj, counter) {
        for (var i in obj) {
            console.log(Array(counter + 1).join("-") + " " + i);
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                if (obj[i] != null) {
                    objectOutput(obj[i], counter + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    objectOutput(objectStr, 0);
```

I would also change regex this way:

```js
    var str = "(id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id),lastname),location)";

    str = str.replace(/\(/g, "{").replace(/\)/g, "}");
    str = str.replace(/([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s*([,{}])/g, function(m, name, x){
        return '"'+name+'":' + (x != '{' ? 'null' : '') + x;});
    var objectStr = JSON.parse(str);

    var objectOutput = function(obj, counter) {
        for (var i in obj) {
            console.log(Array(counter + 1).join("-") + " " + i);
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                if (obj[i] != null) {
                    objectOutput(obj[i], counter + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    objectOutput(objectStr, 0);
```

Comment: Ah, so the screw up wasn't in the regex conversion it was resetting the counter. I just realized I misread my object, the codepen console wasn't showing the second id (for performance reasons? no idea). And the single tics are still odd (If you throw a console.log(str) right before the JSON.parse), but it all works out. Thanks!

Comment: @Organiccat Yes, your regex kind of worked ok, as long as input strings do not contain unexpected characters. Check alternative regex in my answer that does the same.